# Can't set dates of android calendar events when using ContentValues api

Tags: android

I'm trying to insert events in to a calendar i created. I'm using the following code to do so... it's taken from google's documentation on CalendarProvider.

The problem is that no matter what values i put in DTSTART or DTEND the event is always created as a single day event and the date is the current date.

I've also tried to use Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT) with .putExtra for the dates... but sadly this doesn't help as well... neither the dates are set nor it gives me to modify them in the edit intent.

Any Idea what might be causing this behavior?

```
 ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
    event.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, e.getCalendarId());
    event.put(Events.TITLE, e.getTitle());
    event.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, e.getDescription());

    event.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());
    event.put(Events.EVENT_END_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());

    event.put(Events.GUESTS_CAN_MODIFY, 1);
    event.put(Events.IS_ORGANIZER, 1);

    event.put(Events.DTSTART, e.getDateStart());
    event.put(Events.DTEND, e.getDateEnd());
    event.put(Events.ALL_DAY, 1);

    event.putNull(Events.DURATION);
    event.putNull(Events.RRULE);
    event.putNull(Events.RDATE);

    Uri eventUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, event);
    int eventID = Integer.parseInt(eventUri.getLastPathSegment());
```